# osm2pgsql - can't find "maxspeed" tag after import

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have imported a compressed osm file ".pbf" in a PostGIS database with osm2pgsql using the following command:

```
osm2pgsql -c -d osm_france -U postgres -H localhost -S default.style -C 10000 france-latest.osm.pbf
```

Everything was fine, except that I can not find the "maxspeed" information  in any of the tables "planet_osm_roads" and "planet_osm_line." Does the PBF file contain this information? If it contains it, how can I extract it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default.style file https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style does not pick maxspeed into its own column. Edit default.style or use the --hstore option for writing all the tags into hstore.

Comment: I added this to the default.style 
"node,way   maxspeed  text  linear"
And it work fine, thanks a lot